# Return an array with all selected options in a form

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create an array with all selected options in a form on change of any option in the form. But I keep on getting this error

> ```
> TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...document.getElementsByClassName('form-select').addEventListener...')"
> ```

I also tried `document.querySelectorAll('select[class="form-select"]').addEventListner` with the same result.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('form-select').addEventListener("change", function() {


  var array = []
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('option:checked')

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    array.push(checkboxes[i].value)
    console.log(array);
  }

});
```

```css
.form-select{
   width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <form>
     
     <select class="form-select">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
      </select>

      <select class="form-select">
        <option>three</option>
        <option>four</option>
      </select>

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, not a `Node`. You can't attach events to a list.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a nodelist, you cant call `addEventlistener` on that, but you'll need to loop over the results first

Comment: Thanks all, really stupid since I use the eventlistner to kick off another function to iterate over a node list ‍♂️